# Does an url shortener like bit.ly or goo.gl hide the source where this shortened url is placed?

Tags: url, statistics, hide, tracking, url-shortener

I mean, when I place a shortened link in my online portfolio to a site which I built, will my client be able to see that I linked to him from my portfolio site? (via his stats or analytics). He saw my direct link, so now I want to sort-of hide my portfolio link behind shortnened url. Will that work?

Comment: No, they don't hide the referer. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/33530

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From bit.ly: https://bitly.com/a/help#i_3_5

> Why don't my bitly links show up in my server logs?
>
> bitly uses 301 permanent redirects. That means that the referring site
>   is passed through to your server transparently, which is why you don't
>   see bitly in your logs. This is by design, as it preserves the genuine
>   referring sites, as well as the original page rank.

You'd have to check the docs of other url shorteners, or operate your own (http://yourls.org/).

Answer (score 0):

His stats/analytics will show the shortened link as the referer, not your porrfolio site where the link has been placed, if that's what you mean.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. Thanks. But I did some testing with Goo.gl and it appears that the original referrer (my portfolio) does show up in the stats whether I use a shortened link or not.

Comment: I (my client) uses [Goliath](http://www.goliath.nl/) it's quite basic but very convenient. @firian